# How to use time() as equal query to get date

Tags: php, mysqli

I have insert php time() example(005558883333) at MySQL table. I want to equal date from `mysqli` query.
I have inserted php time() as int type in MySQL table
example:

```
select lastdate from create_date=time();
```

[image]

Comment: could you clarify what you mean please? Do you want to convert the time to a date or perform a `where` clause using the time as a date??

Comment: i have insert time() as int type. I want use as select query to get equal date.But i have used time() as int type

Comment: i want use example

Comment: SELECT * FROM `al_brand` WHERE create_time='12-12-2017'

Answer (score 1):

I think, if I have understood correctly that what you need is `from_unixtime` - so taking one of the integers in the table:

```
set @t=1547554662;
select from_unixtime( @t );
```

Will output:

```
2019-01-15 12:17:42
```

You can therefore use `from_unixtime` in a where clause should you wish to query by date. Does that help?

ie: possibly do this...

```
SELECT * FROM al_brand WHERE date( from_unixtime( create_time ) )='12-12-2017';
```

To get simply the date and omit the time portion

```
select date(from_unixtime( @t ));
```

Comment: i want only date not time

Comment: //------------------------date time from time()------------------------------------
select from_unixtime(create_time,'%d/%m/%Y') as creatdate FROM al_brand
select from_unixtime(create_time) as creatdate FROM al_brand
//------------------------end------------------------------------

Comment: ? is that a question? If the answer helps solve the problem please accept the answer to indicate it is solved